# Printf didn't display the first one, just after that ones

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* foo (const char* str)
{
    char szo[125];
    char* vege;
        int i,j=0;
        int db=1;
        szo[0] = str[0];
        for(i=1; i<strlen(str)+1; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == str[i-1] )
            {
                    db++;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
                szo[j] = db + '0';
                j++;
                szo[j] = str[i];
                db=1;
            }
        }
        j++;
        szo[j] = '\0';
        vege = szo;
    return vege;
}

int main()
{
    char *s[] = {"hello", "world", "Mississippi"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(char *); ++i)
    {
        char *p = foo(s[i]);
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've tried to do first a printf("\n"), then its good, but i have a empty first line.
Someone can please help me.Thanks a lot.
Or if anyone can help me, the original tasks say a free(p) in the main after the printf, how can i change everything to work with malloc?

Comment: foo is returning a pointer to local memory which is gone after the return.

Comment: `foo` is returning the address of a local variable on the stack, which you then proceed to use in `main` resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  Do not mix tabs and spaces when indenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`szo` ceases to exist right before `foo()` returns.
Yet you return a pointer to that array and try to use it outside the function.

If you're not ever going to call `foo` recursively, or in parallel in several threads, or as different arguments of another function, try `static char szo[125];` **and remember to document that the function returns a pointer to a static array** so that you don't invoke UB in 6 months time

```
char *foo(const char *str) {
    static char szo[125];
    //...
    return szo;
}

printf("%s\n", foo("something")); //ok
printf("%s\n", foo("some other thing")); //ok
//printf("%s\n%s\n", foo("something"), foo("some other thing")); //NO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* foo (const char* str)
{
    char szo[125];    
    ...
    vege = szo;
    return vege;
}
```

you return pointer to the local variable which does not exist after the return from the function. One of the most common UBs